# Почему у свежесозданной метки есть один подписчик?

Tags: поддержка, метки

Создал метку [vhdl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl). У неё почему-то сразу есть подписчик (и это не я). Откуда?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кстати, видно рассогласование с числом у "вопросов".

Comment: скорее всего автор метки автоматом подписывается.

Comment: @Grundy нажал "подписаться", стало два подписчика. Похоже, что первый — не я.

Comment: А нельзя посмотреть подписчиков?

Comment: @Grundy не нашёл такой опции.

Comment: может 1 подписчик - Дух?

Comment: @pavel неа, бывают метки без подписки. Да и зачем ему подписка, он же вездесущий.

Comment: Может метка была раньше с одним подписчиком и ее удалили? А теперь она восстала из пепла?

Comment: Нашел на Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167382/339911

Comment: Не воспроизводится: у моей свежесозданной метки 0 подписчиков. Вероятно, да, кто-то подписался на несуществующую метку, или же эта метка была раньше. Спасибо.